# Reemplazar mes expresión regular

Tags: regex

Solicito de su ayuda para validar si la siguiente expresión cubre todo los casos, lo he pasado por un editor online y el resultado es el esperado, pero puedo estar dejando un caso por fuera.

**Palabra:** `AL052587OCT`

**Expresion:** `\b(ENE)|(FEB)|(MAR)|(ABR)|(MAY)|(JUN)|(JUL)|(AGO)|(SEP)|(OCT)|(NOV)|(DIC)`

**Valor esperado:** `AL052587`

Adicionalmente a ésto, le estoy quitando los espacios en blanco. ¿es posible integrar los dos en una sola expresión...?

**Eliminar espacios en blanco:** `(^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un regex más acotado sería el siguiente:

```
/(^\s+|\s+|\s+(?=\s)|ENE|FEB|MAR|ABR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AGO|SEP|OCT|NOV|DIC)/gmi
```

Si la cadena de texto que indicaste respeta siempre la misma estructura, estarían incluidos todos los casos (los doce meses), así como también espacios al inicio, al final y entre caracteres.

Un problema que podría ocurrir con este regex unificado, es que si pudieran existir espacios entre las letras que conforman el mes, éste no se borraría. Si se puede dar ese caso, deberías correr las sentencias separadas, primero la eliminación de espacios y luego la del mes.

Comment: O cambiar `ENE` por `E\s*N\s*E` y así con todos los demás meses.

Comment: @DCC me podrias por favor explicar que quiere decir `gmi` o que hace...?

Comment: @Gdaimon **g** significa **global**, es decir busca los textos todas las veces que aparezcan. **m** significa **multiline**, si el texto tiene más de una línea. **i** significa **insensitive**, por lo que buscará tanto en mayúsculas como en minúsculas. No es necesario que utilices estos flags, salgo el **g**, sólo están como ejemplo. También dependerá del lenguaje que utilices para aplicarlos, no todos los aplican de la misma manera.